# usj/ajax remote call not works, page goes to the target url rather than stay in the same page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ujs

My expeactation is **after clicking the remote link**

**The partial will be updated** and the browser should stay in the same page.

But current behavior is **The browser heads to the remote-link url**, and gives me the error

error `ActionController::UnknownFormat in ProductsController#filter_products`

#### index.haml

```
= link_to cate.name , filter_products_path(cate.id) , remote: true, method: :post, id: cate.id
```

#### routes.rb

```
get 'products/filter_products/:category' => 'products#filter_products', as: :filter_products
```

#### controller

```
  def filter_products
    @products = ProductCategory.where("id = ?",params["category"].to_i).first.products
    respond_to do |format|
      format.js
   end
  end
```

#### application.js

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require_tree .
```

Comment: filter_products is a get or post method?

Comment: I think i defined it as `get` method in the route

Comment: Off topic: do you ever accept a right answer? Or you just pass by and ask your next question?

Answer (score 0):

You set the link in routes to have a `GET` method, but in link you override it as `POST` with:

`..., method: :post, ...`

so it will look for this route as a post method that you don't have. Your link should be:

```
= link_to cate.name , filter_products_path(cate.id) , remote: true, id: cate.id
```

without `method`, it will be as `GET` by default.